# How to the blur the image in silver appbar as we scroll up in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to have an effect where as the user scrolls up it shows the background color of SilverAppBar. Instead, I want the image that I added in the background should be blurred as I scroll up instead of showing the color. I was trying to achieve this with `CustomScrollView` and silvers but I think this is not the correct path.